# mySQL syntax error when using an integer

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to create a table using mySQL and Java. What I have is:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Userinput.getTableName2() +
" (participant INT(255), " +
" 0 INT(255),"+ 
" name INT(3), " + 
" occurances INT(255))";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

The Zero naming the second column is arbitrary, but I will need to have the column name be an integer. 
The error I'm getting is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '0 INT(255), name INT(3),  occurances INT(255))' at line 1

I would appreciate any and all help! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist
>   solely of digits.

so you have to quote the `0`

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Userinput.getTableName2() +
" (participant INT(255), " +
" `0` INT(255),"+                     // using backticks
" name INT(3), " + 
" occurances INT(255))";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Although, it seems a dumb name for a column.

Comment: The better way to quote the identifier is using backticks.  To quote the documentation:  "The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”)" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: Hi, I had tried adding the single quotes in before as per the documentation, but I receive a very similar error when i do so. "MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0' INT(255), name INT(3),  occurances INT(255))' at line 1"

Comment: @GordonLinoff Using backsticks seemed to fix my error! Thanks! and thank you user2310289 for your suggestion too!

Comment: +1 For being right, but mostly because `0` really does seem like a dumb name for a column.

Answer (score 0):

Please read mysql documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist
>   solely of digits.